# weird TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, generator

I encounter a weird error. As these codes, both `foo()` and `bar()` return `None`, but it raises TypeError only when iterating `bar()`

```
def foo():
  if True:
    return

  yield 1, 2

def bar():
  return

for a, b in foo():
  print a + b

for a, b in bar():
  print a + b
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `foo` includes a `yield` statement, it is a generator, so the result from the return is always a generator object even if the actual yield statement can't be reached. A generator is true in a boolean sense, hence your result.

Answer (score 2):

If your function does not include **yield** statement and you want it to return "empty iterator" you should write

```
def empty()
    raise StopIteration

for each in empty():
    print('this will never show up')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you

```
print foo()
print bar()
```

you get

```
<generator object foo at 0x7f8a79fd5eb0>
None
```

Answer (score 1):

The yield 1, 2 makes the difference.
foo returns:

```
<generator object foo at 0x7f9e01a91d70>
```

bar returns:

```
None
```

If you'd comment the yield part the code would crash on foo() too.

You should return two values for each of the methods to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

In your functions `foo` and `bar`, they both reach an empty `return` statement. They implicitly `return None`. `foo` will nonetheless generate an iterator as it includes a `yield` statement.

Therefore as you are looping over the output of the functions, `foo` will use the iterator values, while `bar` will not, resulting in a `TypeError`.